# Accessing all views of list_item in listview android

Tags: android, listview

I have two textviews and one imageview in my list_item_layout I want to perform some operations on each view when clicked.How do I do it?Also i have to perform delete action when long pressed on list item layout.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:background="@drawable/rectangle_shadow"
android:orientation="horizontal">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/t1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fontFamily="monospace"
        android:minHeight="30dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />



<TextView
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:id="@+id/t2"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textStyle="italic"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/word_list_popup_menu_button"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `OnClickListener` for each of this views in `getView()` method of your adapter:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.t1 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.t1);
        viewHolder.t1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        viewHolder.t2 = convertView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
        viewHolder.t2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        viewHolder.word_list_popup_menu_button = convertView.findViewById(R.id.word_list_popup_menu_button);
        viewHolder.word_list_popup_menu_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView t1;
    TextView t2;
    ImageView word_list_popup_menu_button;
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you help me doing this stuff in onCreateView method in fragment, not in adapter class.Not sure what if there is any difference between doing it in adapter class and in fragment,but most of similar questions suggested the other way.

Comment: If you use a ListView you need to create an adapter for it. Attach the source code of that fragment please

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the [guides](http://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html) outlined for `RecyclerView`, they'll explain how you bind to your layout and the views you're interested in using `ViewHolders`. This is because of the fundamental way `RecyclerViews` (and `ListViews`) work - they don't hold all their items at once, instead they re-use views to increase performance.

All that's in the guides though, that's where I and everyone else learned it from!